# await promise function repeated but resolve/ return failed in 2nd

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I am studying await promises in `node.js`
The following program is run by calling `main()` at the bottom.
`main()` calls the function `caller()`. `caller()` then calls function `loop()` which is a timeout of  2 seconds and return a message ***I waited 2 sec.***  `loop()` returns to `caller()`, then `caller()` returns to `main()`, merely to pass the same messages.

**caller() and main() are practically the same codes** and they should return the same way !!
But return to main() is undefined.

Eclipse run result:

> C:\Users\Lenovo\eclipse-workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wildwebdeveloper.embedder.node\node-v14.15.4-win-x64\node.exe
> awaitPromise2.js "  Top Level starts.. main start ... in loop, start
> aaa : New loop, finished output :  Message: I waited 1 sec. in caller
> aaa : Message: I waited 1 sec. in caller, resolve  aaa  :  Message: I
> waited 1 sec. in main, response :undefined in main, resolve result :
> undefined

The program file is:

```js
async function loop() {
  let aaa = "New";
  console.log("in loop, start aaa : " + aaa);
  await new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));
  aaa = " Message: I waited 2 sec.";
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    console.log("loop, finished output : " + aaa);
    resolve(aaa);
    return;
  });
}

async function caller() {
  await loop().then(function (aaa) {
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(resolve, 3000));
    console.log("in caller aaa :" + aaa);
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(resolve, 1500));
      let bbb = aaa;
      console.log("in caller, resolve  aaa  : " + bbb);
      resolve(bbb);
    });
  });
}

async function main() {
  console.log("main start ...");
  await caller().then(function (aaa) {
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(resolve, 5000));

    console.log("in main, response :" + aaa);

    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(resolve, 6000));
      console.log("in main, resolve result : " + aaa);
      resolve(aaa);
      return;
    });
  });
}

console.log(" Top Level starts..");
main();
```

I made uses of timeout trying to wait for results to come. Are they needed??

Comment: Don't mix `.then()` with `await` syntax, don't put anything more than `setTimeout` inside the `new Promise` executor, do remove all the `new Promise`s that you resolve immediately, and do remove all the `new Promise`s that you don't do anything with.

Comment: Your `caller` function does not `return` anything. Adjusting the indentation might help you see why.

Comment: @Bergi in addition, `main()` also doesn't `return` anything. For the same reason `caller()` doesn't.

Comment: Thank you for prompt reply. I put exactly  same codes for the return in the loop() too. It worked.   Seeing your comment(s),  I put a line  "return" after the resolve(bbb) in caller(), But no change . Please explain more how to return the  resolve of variable bbb?

Comment: The codes in loop() ,  caller()  (and main()) for return are the same but caller() get the resolve from loop(). Any explanation? Will the setTimeout() value for delay important to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's remove all the superfluous stuff from the code that did nothing:

```
async function loop() {
  let aaa = "New";
  console.log("in loop, start aaa : " + aaa);
  await new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));
  aaa = " Message: I waited 2 sec.";
  console.log("loop, finished output : " + aaa);
  return Promise.resolve(aaa);
}

async function caller() {
  await loop().then(function (aaa) {
    console.log("in caller aaa :" + aaa);
    let bbb = aaa;
    console.log("in caller, resolve  aaa  : " + bbb);
    return Promise.resolve(bbb);
  });
}

async function main() {
  console.log("main start ...");
  await caller().then(function (aaa) {
    console.log("in main, response :" + aaa);
    console.log("in main, resolve result : " + aaa);
    return Promise.resolve(aaa);
  });
}

console.log(" Top Level starts..");
main();
```

Now the problem is clear to see: `caller` doesn't `return` a value. The only `return` statement it contains is inside the `.then()` callback, resolving the promise that is `await`ed, but afterwards nothing happens with that. To fix that, `return` the promise chain instead of only `await`ing it:

```
function caller() {
  return loop().then(function (aaa) {
    console.log("in caller, aaa: " + aaa);
    return Promise.resolve(aaa);
  });
}
```

Or better don't use `.then()` chaining when you can use `async`/`await` everywhere. Also you can omit `Promise.resolve` from return values in `async` functions or `.then` callbacks:

```
async function loop() {
  const aaa = "New";
  console.log("in loop, start: " + aaa);
  await new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));
  const bbb = "Message: I waited 2 sec.";
  console.log("loop, finished output: " + bbb);
  return bbb;
}

async function caller() {
  const bbb = await loop();
  console.log("in caller:" + bbb);
  return bbb;
}

async function main() {
  console.log("main start ...");
  const res = await caller();
  console.log("in main, response: " + res);
  // return res; // unused anyway
}

console.log("Top Level starts...");
main();
```

Comment: Thank you Bergi, The codes are neat , clean and short.  I have struggled for 2 days to debug

Answer (score 1):

Man, you just missed a `return` in the caller. Or, you used `await` incorrectly. Because you used `await` the result is not returned unless return is called.

```js
async function loop() {
          let aaa = "New";
          console.log("in loop, start aaa : " + aaa);
          await new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));
          aaa = " Message: I waited 2 sec.";
          return new Promise((resolve) => {
            console.log("loop, finished output : " + aaa);
            resolve(aaa);
            return;
          });
        }

        async function caller() {
          return await loop().then(function (aaa) {
            new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(resolve, 3000));
            console.log("in caller aaa :" + aaa);
            return new Promise((resolve) => {
              new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(resolve, 1500));
              let bbb = aaa;
              console.log("in caller, resolve  aaa  : " + bbb);
              resolve(bbb);
            });
          });
        }

        async function main() {
          console.log("main start ...");
          await caller().then(function (aaa) {
            new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(resolve, 5000));

            console.log("in main, response :" + aaa);

            return new Promise((resolve) => {
              new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(resolve, 6000));
              console.log("in main, resolve result : " + aaa);
              resolve(aaa);
              return;
            });
          });
        }

        console.log(" Top Level starts..");
        main();
```

I suggest you do not mix `async` with `.then`, you should pick one and stick with it.

I suggest you ditch the `async/await` in `caller()`, it is much easier to understand:

```js
async function loop() {
          let aaa = "New";
          console.log("in loop, start aaa : " + aaa);
          await new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));
          aaa = " Message: I waited 2 sec.";
          return new Promise((resolve) => {
            console.log("loop, finished output : " + aaa);
            resolve(aaa);
            return;
          });
        }

        function caller() {
          return loop().then(function (aaa) {
            new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(resolve, 3000));
            console.log("in caller aaa :" + aaa);
            return new Promise((resolve) => {
              new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(resolve, 1500));
              let bbb = aaa;
              console.log("in caller, resolve  aaa  : " + bbb);
              resolve(bbb);
            });
          });
        }

        async function main() {
          console.log("main start ...");
          await caller().then(function (aaa) {
            new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(resolve, 5000));

            console.log("in main, response :" + aaa);

            return new Promise((resolve) => {
              new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(resolve, 6000));
              console.log("in main, resolve result : " + aaa);
              resolve(aaa);
              return;
            });
          });
        }

        console.log(" Top Level starts..");
        main();
```

*If you're a new learner, I challenge you to try rewriting your code not to use `.then` entirely and then the other way around - not using `async/await` at all.*

Comment: Thank you so much, kvetis. Great to end my 2 days search for debug.

Comment: Glad you liked it. It would make me proud if you mark it as the accepted answer. Good look with development.